# Adjust number formatting in Excel via xlwings from python

Tags: python, excel, vba, number-formatting, xlwings

I have started using xlwings to create an excel tool which calls a python code. I think it is super useful and at the same time user-friendly as everybody is used to have excel as GUI.

Now to my problem: The tool works well. However, I am left with some formatting. Currently I am able to do some formatting (range(XX).number_format = XX ), but I have not managed to create my desired format.

I want to have comma separated numbers without decimals.

```
sht = xw.Book.caller().sheets[0]

sht.range('C:D').number_format = '0.00' (1)

sht.range('C:D').number_format = 'General' (2)

sht.range('C:D').number_format = '#’##0' (3)
```

(1): This works. However, numbers are not comma separated (as expected)

(2): Does not work. Python runs and runs, nothing happens. (same for 'Number')

(3): Produces desired results on my machine/ my excel version. However, on my friend's excel it looks different and does not produce the desired results anymore.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try `"#,##0"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried this, but it does not work. The numbers are not displayed in the usual comma separated format.

Comment: `Produces desired results on my machine/ my excel version. However, on my friend's excel it looks different` Can you give an example? I do not know python but I can try and help?

Comment: It could be that your Excel uses a different character instead of `.` (point) as decimal separator or `,` (comma) as thousands separator (e.g., because of using Excel in a different language than English). If that is the case you would need to set point as decimal separator and probably comma as thousands seperator (here is an [instruction](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e)), otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the format in thousands and seperate by comma, I tried this,

```
number_format = "#,##0"
```

and it works perfectly in my case.